# Efficiently obtaining nonzero element coordinates of sparse matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I want to get the row-column coordinates for all nonzero elements in a matrix `M`. If `M` isn't too big, it's straightforward:

```
m <- matrix(sample(0:1, 25, TRUE, prob=c(0.75, 0.25)), 5, 5)

     #[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    1    1    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    1    0
#[4,]    0    0    1    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    0

nz <- which(m != 0)
cbind(row(m)[nz], col(m)[nz])

     #[,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    1
#[2,]    2    2
#[3,]    4    3
#[4,]    3    4
```

However, in my case `M` is a sparse matrix (created using the Matrix package), whose dimensions can be very large. If I call `row(M)` and `col(M)` like above, I'll be generating a couple of dense matrices the same size as `M`, which I definitely don't want to do.

Is there a way of getting a result like the above without creating dense matrices along the way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want

```
which(m!=0,arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Looking at `showMethods("which")`, it seems that this is set up to work efficiently with sparse matrices. You can also get the answer more directly (but inscrutably) for a sparse, column-oriented matrix by manipulating the internal `@p` (column pointer) and `@i` (row pointer) slots:

```
mm <- Matrix(m)
dp <- diff(mm@p)
cbind(mm@i+1,rep(seq_along(dp),dp))
```

Comment: Confirmed that it works: `M <- Matrix(0, nrow=35000, ncol=35000, sparse=TRUE); M[1, 1] <- 1; which(M != 0, arr.ind=TRUE)` doesn't blow up my computer

Comment: Turns out I also need the zero elements and that _does_ blow up my computer, but that's for another question, I guess

Comment: because the result is too large? `m==0` should still be a logical sparse matrix.  You could set up an iterator to list zero elements a column at a time ...

Comment: Well, in my 35000x35000 example above, `M == 0` would be a "sparse" matrix with 35000^2 - 1 `TRUE`s. But what I really want is a random sample from the nonzeros which is the same length as the zeros. I might have to set up an iterator as you suggest.